# Panel Data regression (FE) reduces R^2 to near 0 from 0.36 under SLR

Tags: r, linear-regression, panel-data

I am running a regression analysis on GDP per capita and CO2 emissions per capita. The SLR gives quite satisfactory results and a low p-value to indicate the validity of the model.

[image]

However, if i run a Panel Data regression with Fixed Effects my R^2 is reduced to almost 0. This would just invalidate the model, if it weren't for the unusually high p-value of 0,4.

[image]

Is it possible for the Fixed Effects to be this significant and counter-indicative of the first regression, or am i making a mistake in how i analyse the data sets?

Comment: I am not familiar with the `plm` function, but it looks like it expects some specification of which columns represent the time and/or individual data (see `pdata.frame`). Your formula and function call do not appear to specify either of these. Note that the `lm` result has 174 degrees of freedom, while the `plm` result has 703.

Comment: Your suggestion regarding the additional specifications needed was right, I didn't enter them correctly before. The DoF are still not favorable but the R^2 looks much better and the p-value is way within significance now, thank you for your help